# check if a array list contain data start with "" Windows phone 7 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to check if a array list contains a string that starts with "apple".

Is it possible that if it exist will show the data that start with "apple"?

```
foreach (var reminder1 in reminderSplit)
{
    MessageBox.Show(reminder1);
    if (reminder1.StartsWith("apple"))
    {
        string home = reminder1.StartsWith("apple").ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("Have : " + home);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to change `if (reminder1.StartsWith("apple"))` to `if (reminder1.ToLower().StartsWith("apple"))` in this case you get message box if reminder starts with "Apple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course:

```
foreach (var reminder1 in reminderSplit)
{
    MessageBox.Show(reminder1);
    if (reminder1.StartsWith("apple"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Have : " + reminder1);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to exclude "apple", then you can replace the display code with the following:

```
MessageBox.Show("Have : " + reminder1.Substring("apple".Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with LINQ:

```
var apples = from s in reminderSplit
             where s.StartsWith("apple", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             select s;
```

or, if you prefer something terser:

```
var apples = reminderSplit
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("apple", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Note that you can specify a type of string comparison - this particular comparison will perform a culture- and case-insensitive match, which will match "Applesauce" and "applesauce" equally.